# how to get the Handler of the main ui thread?

Tags: android, android-handler

using `SurfaceTexture` i need to call this function :

```
setOnFrameAvailableListener (SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener listener, 
                Handler handler)
```

I would like to gave the Handler of the main UI thread, but I don't know how to get it ...

**NOTE**: i know i can do `Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());` but their is not an already created object of Handler accessible somewhere ?

Comment: Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Comment: thanks @BapusahebShinde - but their is not an already created object of Handler accessible somewhere ?

Comment: no, there is no default UI `Handler`, are you calling `setOnFrameAvailableListener` from some background `Thread`?

Comment: no actually i call it from the main ui thread but the doc say we must gave an handler else OnFrameAvailableListener will be called on an arbitrary thread :(

Comment: then if you pass `null` it will be called on the same ui thread - see [here](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.java#199)

Answer (score 0):

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("BGHandler") // string here can be any name
handlerThread.start()
surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this, Handler(handlerThread.getLooper())) //this means that the class calling this function implements the interface, I am sure u understand that since you have not asked for it, but if necessary I can elaborate more, just ask in the comments
```